# How to send text field data from one view controller to multiple view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have few text fields and want to send their data to multiple view controllers depending upon the button clicked. It is not working. Any suggestions??my segue controller is as follows:

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  var destViewController : myViewControllerFavourites = segue.destinationViewController as myViewControllerFavourites;

            var destViewController1 : myViewController2ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as myViewController2ViewController ;

            destViewController.labelText = textField.text;
            destViewController1.labelTextNew = anotherTextField.text;
        }
```

Comment: How on earth is this possible that your destination view controller can be casted into two classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it would be easy to store all information in a global variable or `NSUserDefaults` and then in new `UIViewController` in function `viewDidLoad` just change your labels' text

Answer (score 1):

You should store the data either via some model layer, a manager or in NSUserDefaults and then send a notification that the observed data has been updated.
Register all relevant view controllers as observers and once they get the notification they should query the new data from the model and update the UI.
HTH